# SQL SELECT statement from $_POST

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to build a SQL `SELECT` statement from information collected through an html form, stored in the `$_POST` array. My difficulty arises because the statement must vary according to user's inputs.

I have 2 dropdown menus, whose values are stored in `$_POST['flow']` and `$_POST['tables']`, respectively. So far so good.

Then I've 4 checkboxes for countries and 15 for years. The first stored in the array `$_POST['country']` and the second in `$_POST['year']`.

I've tried to build the SQL statement through foreach loops like this:

```
<?php 
//Define SQL SELECT statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$_POST['tables']." WHERE FlowType = '".$_POST['flow']."' AND (";

    foreach ($_POST['country'] as $value) {
        $sql .= "Reporter = '$value' OR ";
    }

    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -3);
    $sql .= ") AND (";

    foreach ($_POST['year'] as $value) {
        $sql .= "TradeYear = '$value' OR ";
    }

    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -4);
    $sql .= ")";

    echo $sql;
?>
```

It works, yet I have a feeling it could be implemented differently. Moreover, it will be complicated to apply prepared statements for PDO query with this method.

Any suggestions? I'd appreciate some inputs on this since my knowledge on PHP (and programming in general) is very basic. Thank you!

Comment: Use `WHERE IN ()`

Comment: This code is not going to be used in production, right? This is some web dev 101 course, right? *smiles nervously and sweats profusely*

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, it definitely is a web dev 101 level question. But you've to start somewhere xD

Comment: It will be more complicated to recover your database after it's deleted by someone who's hostile. This code is so full of holes it will whistle if it moves fast. **Use prepared statements**. This is not hard to get right. You can name every placeholder you use and then bind to those using an associative array.

Comment: If you want an example of how to do this more safely look at how an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) allows you to express your code as a series of clauses optionally appended to a query.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to use prepared statements on all my input data. But since I use IN statements I've to say it was a pain in the ass xD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ignoring my comment from above, this should work (albeit, totally unsafe):

```
<?php 
//Define SQL SELECT statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$_POST['tables']." WHERE FlowType = '".$_POST['flow'];

if(isset($_POST['country']) && is_array($_POST['country']) && count($_POST['country']) > 0)
{
    $sql.= " AND Reporter in ('".implode("','", $_POST['country'])."')";
}

if(isset($_POST['year']) && is_array($_POST['year']) && count($_POST['year']) > 0)
{
    $sql.= " AND TradeYear in ('".implode("','", $_POST['year'])."')";
}

echo $sql;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Like I said, my knowledge on programming is very basic. How can I make it safer?

Comment: @FranciscoVenes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php